# How to make my service only run in one instance in multiple user android system?

Tags: android, android-service, android-manifest, android-service-binding

Our android system supports multiple user feature. I'd like to start my server from other apps, like app1, app2 with command startService(intent).
Per google's document at https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multiuser-apps.html.
I need to set android:singleUser="true" to make sure my service only running in one instance in multiple user android system. but when I startservice in other app, I got below exception:

```
Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.xx.xxx.action.Start pkg=com.xx.xxx (has extras) } without permission not exported from uid 1000
```

it seemed android:exported="true" was disabled by android:singleUser="true". if I didn't add android:singleUser="true", it worked fine, but there are more than one instance of my service running in background.
My question is how can I make my service only running in one single instance with startService(intent) from other apps?
My Manifest.xml is configured as below:

```
    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:directBootAware="true"
        android:multiprocess="false"
        android:persistent="true">
        <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:singleUser="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.xx.permission.xx">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.xx.xx.action.xx" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
</Application>
```

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Need to declare app as system app. also use bindServiceAsUser() with System UserHandler.

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation you linked says: "only system apps can currently use this feature". If it's feasible for your product, make your app a system app.

Answer (score 1):

You need the INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL permission at allow binding to a single instance service from a non primary user. It is a signature only permission so your app needs to be signed with the platform keys.

Answer (score 0):

1. make android:exported and android:singleUser to true
2. add permission INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS
3. make sure you app is  privileged. so you should make your app system signature