# android:singleuser=1 not working correctly , multiple service for multiple user getting created

Tags: java, android

```
android_app {
    name: "ClusterEditModeService",
    //proprietary: true, true means vendor
    product_specific: true,
    srcs: [
        "java/**/*.java",
```

`id="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.harman.clustereditmode"
android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system">

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_USERS"/>

<application android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:persistent="true"
    android:enabled="true">
    <uses-library android:name="Clustereditmode_aidl" />
    <service android:name=".ClustereditmodeService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:singleUser="true">
    </service>

    <receiver android:name=".BootCompleteReceiver"
            android:singleUser="true"
            android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_USER_SWITCHED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

</manifest>`

Above are my files content.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make my service only run in one instance in multiple user android system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081137/how-to-make-my-service-only-run-in-one-instance-in-multiple-user-android-system)

Comment: how to make an app system app, installing in SYSTEM user makes app system app??